# Handle slash ('/') in a URL CodeIgniter

Tags: php, url-rewriting, urlencode, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-url

I am creating a site using CodeIgniter. I have an url like `http://mysite.com/albums/MJ/Dangerous.html` where `MJ` is the artist name and `Dangerous` is the name of the album. Both of these are dynamic and fetched from a database.

In the database there are some albums which have a slash ('/') character in them. So, such an URL becomes `http://mysite.com/albums/50-cent/Get+Rich+or+Die+Tryin%27%2FThe+Massacre.html`. On decoding, it turns out as `http://ringtones/albums/50-cent/Get Rich or Die Tryin'/The Massacre.html`. Here the artist is `50-cent` and the album name is `Get Rich or Die Tryin'/The Massacre`

My question is, what do I do so that I get the entire album name, i.e. `Get Rich or Die Tryin'/The Massacre.html` as a single argument with the slash character? Currently CodeIgniter shows an error as "Page not found" when I click on such an URL. All other URL's which doesn't have the `/` works fine.

Answer (score 4):

Try double URLencoding the album name (i.e. `urlencode(urlencode($album))`). I was trying to pass a URL once to a CodeIgniter controller and it constantly gave me troubles. So I just double encoded it, and then it popped through on the other side no problem. I then ran an urldecode() on the passed parameter.

Let me know if that helps you.

Answer (score 1):

As per current SEO trend no need to bring the quote in url or to fetch on page.
instead during saving (in slag kind of field) and retrieving you can use this kind of option.

```
$base_url = "http://ringtones/";
$controller = "albums";

$artist = "50 cent";
$album = "Get Rich Or Die Tryin' / The Massacre";

$link1 = $base_url.$controller.'/'.url_title($artist,'-',TRUE).'/'.url_title($album,'-',TRUE);
echo $link1;
```

**Result:**

```
http://ringtones/albums/50-cent/get-rich-or-die-tryin-the-massacre
```

Answer (score 1):

`encode` the value before passing

```
$value = str_replace('=', '-', str_replace('/', '_', base64_encode($album)));
```

`decode` the value after receiving

```
$value = base64_decode(str_replace('-', '=', str_replace('_', '/', $value)));
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the HTML escaped version of the characters in your URL...

See below for a reference.

http://www.theukwebdesigncompany.com/articles/entity-escape-characters.php

After HTML encoding, your URL should look something like:

```
http://ringtones/albums/50&#45;cent/Get Rich or Die Tryin&#39;&#47;The Massacre.html
```

I hope this helps!

N

Comment: Should I use htmlentities() function to carry this out?

Comment: I've no idea I'm afraid. I've never used PHP.

Answer (score 0):

You will want to [urlencode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) the album name when the data is retrieved from the model so that blackslash is escaped.

Comment: I am using urlencode but when I click on the link, it gives me a 404

Answer (score 0):

Extending the @MikeMurko answer to include how to work with Javascript and PHP.
Simply go for **double** encoding and decoding;

**JS:**

```
var id = encodeURIComponent( encodeURIComponent('mystring/&-34') );
```

**PHP:**

```
$id = urldecode( urldecode('mystring/&-34') );
```